# Sanitizing text input before submitting to MySQL database

Tags: php, database, pdo, ckeditor, sanitization

I'm currently working on making sure that text that is submitted into the database for a webapplication I am working on is sanitized properly before being submitted to the database, and then retrieved and displayed correctly.

Ignoring the jumble of sanitizing functions that are currently being used (it is currently a mess and breaks things), this is what I plan on doing:

1. Use CKEditor for text input. It automatically converts HTML tags/symbols their HTML entities.
2. Utilize PDO prepared statements to submit the text to the database.

Is this enough to properly sanitize input? I've been reading up on this, and many people say to use magic quotes, however I read that magic quotes is old and most recommend against using it.

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Comment: 1. That's nice, but use data correctly *at the use site* (i.e. encode when emitting HTML); 2. Prepared statements eliminate SQL injection but they *do not* eliminate using data incorrectly in other places (e.g. XSS, HTML, exec injection). Magic quotes were a bad idea that tried - and failed - to fix what #2 addresses. Business rule "sanitization" should be done, but for information correctness, and not [necessarily] data injection viewpoint.

Comment: @pst so I should do what everyone else is saying and use htmlspecialchars when outputting the input from the database? Will that interfere with CKEditor replacing HTML tags/symbols with their entities?

Comment: Yes, *always* encode output! (Except if there is a *really* good reason not to.) I personally *do not* encode input. Otherwise there is a blob of .. junk .. in the database. Store the information for what it *supposed* to be. While it might make sense to convert contents of an "rich text" editor into a normalized format (e.g. markdown/markup/bbcode), I would not recommend storing it "html encoded", as databases don't care about HTML. However, Business Rules might dictate that only `<em>` and `<a>` elements are allowed - now *this* should be enforced as it is *part* of the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, PDO is okay only with basic cases from beginners manual.
Whatever complex issue will bring PDO into trouble as well as any other API.

But as long as you are ready to waste your time writing huge insert statements, repeating every variable six to ten times following all these answers round here - PDO is okay.

But just to let you know, there is no prepared statement for identifiers.

As for the CKEditor - isn't it a client-side application? If so, it will protect nothing.
So, better follow an advise from another answer - pass untrusted user-input through htmlspecialchars() when displaying it on HTML page

Comment: Thank you for your reply. CKEditor IS a client-side application. One of the reasons I decided to use it was the fact that it replaced HTML tags and symbols with HTML entities... the users who use the application had a VERY bad habit of copying and pasting whatever crap they found into the application, so CKEditor helps set a standard for what is going into the database.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use magic quotes. http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

> This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

If you're using prepared statements then you should be safe from sql injection. Remember to run user-inputted data through `htmlspecialchars()` when displaying it on the front-end.

Comment: So when displaying the information from the database (that will have HTML entities like &#39;) I should use htmlspecialchars before displaying it to the user?